# latest tlmgr update removes mktexlsr?

Tags: tlmgr, texlive-2019

I have vanilla installations of `texlive 2019` on several Linux machines, obtained as described [here](https://www.tug.org/texlive/quickinstall.html). The latest update, which I usually do via

```
tlmgr update --self --all
```

seems to have removed the 'mktexlsr' executable. The output (on all three machines I currently maintain texlive on):

```
tlmgr: package repository <repo; they vary between computers> (verified)                                                                                                                                                             
tlmgr: saving backups to ${HOME}/texlive/2019/tlpkg/backups                                                                                                                                                                          
[1/5, ??:??/??:??] update: kpathsea.x86_64-linux [40k] (50281 -> 53254) ... done                                                                                                                                                     
[2/5, 00:01/02:45] update: newtx [5242k] (52998 -> 53255) ... done                                                                                                                                                                   
[3/5, 00:03/00:03] update: tex4ht [937k] (53251 -> 53257) ... done                                                                                                                                                                   
[4/5, 00:04/00:04] update: texlive-docindex [155k] (53237 -> 53253) ... done                                                                                                                                                         
[5/5, 00:04/00:04] update: texlive-scripts [134k] (53242 -> 53253) ... done                                                                                                                                                          
running mktexlsr ...                                                                                                                                                                                                                 

tlmgr: mktexlsr failed (status -1), output:                                                                                                                                                                                          

running updmap-sys ...                                                                                                                                                                                                               
done running updmap-sys.                                                                                                                                                                                                             
tlmgr: package log updated: /root/texlive/2019/texmf-var/web2c/tlmgr.log                                                                                                                                                             
tlmgr: An error has occurred. See above messages. Exiting.
```

To confirm, I then tried running `mktexlsr` in a terminal. This used to work *immediately* prior to the update (after it happened twice, I tried `mktexlsr` *before* the update on the third machine). The result is that the command is not found. I am sure that the `texlive` binaries are in my path (I can run `pdflatex` fine for instance, as a regular user).

As a sanity check, I looked inside

```
${HOME}/texlive/2019/bin/x86_64-linux/
```

where the binaries live. The `mktexlsr` file there is a *broken* link to

```
../../texmf-dist/scripts/texlive/mktexlsr
```

Comment: see https://tug.org/pipermail/tex-live/2019-December/044612.html

Comment: I see, thanks. I'll keep an eye on it then.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sure enough, this was a temporary glitch and [was fixed](https://tug.org/pipermail/tex-live/2019-December/044618.html) soon afterwards, on the following update.